# WPF: How to Assign data to the DataContext of a Control that is Located in Windows.Resources?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid inside a Canvas. A List of data is assigned to the DataContext of the DataGrid in code behind. Now I am trying to move the Canvas to Windows.Resources in order to create multiple instances from the control when needed. However, when moving the Canvas to resources, it is not recognized anymore from Code Behind. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get datagrid from window resources.

Give `x:Key` to your dataGrid (say `x:Key="MyDataGrid"`) and now in code behind you can get it like this -

```
DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)FindResource("MyDataGrid");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to bind your list of data to the DataContext in the xaml. Try not to do it in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent answers. However, as an alternative I ended up moving the Canvas control with visibility collapsed in the MainGrid, or in other words, outside any Grid the Control is expected to be used within in the future. Now I have control over the Canvas control without repeating any code. Might not be the best solution but just another alternative that works.

The Control could be moved to a new Grid within the main grid, that makes it easy to spot in the Document Outline window.